# Why is my assignment asking me use 172.16.0.0 private addressing and IPv4 sub netted Class C address Scheme?

Tags: ipv4, subnet

I am doing a project for Cybersecurity and trying to build a college campus network. The complete instructions read:

LAN infrastructure layouts for all campuses.

•   Represent multiple building/classroom PCs with two icons showing first and last IP subnet addresses.

•   Basic functional configurations for PCs, servers, switches, and routers.

•   PCs – must have IPv4 addressing configured (static).

•   Servers – must have IPv4 addressing configured (static).

•   Switches – must have IPv4 addressing and login security.

•   Routers – must have IPv4 addressing, login security, and functional routing table (static).

•   IPv4 subnetted class C address scheme.

•   Use 172.16.0.0 private addressing

•   Third octet should be used for subnetting required to support network design criteria.

•   WAN connections between campuses (static).

•   Ability to ping and traceroute within and between campuses.

There are 3 branch college campuses and 1 main campus.
Wouldn't that be a contradiction as the range of Class C addresses are from 192-223 which 172.16.0.0 doesn't fall under or am I not understanding enough about the project?

Comment: You're being too literal. When they say "class C" they mean "/24". Classful networking has been dead for decades. (you're right to call out your instructor(s) for this.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's sloppy writing in the instructions, but I'm pretty sure it means you should use /24 networks (i.e. 172.16.0.0/24, 172.16.1.0/24, 172.16.2.0/24, etc). It would've been better to say to use class-C-*sized* networks, but even that's obsolete terminology since network classes haven't been a thing since 1993.